# Sequence in matrices converging to Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-theory

Let $M_{k}(\mathbb{C})$ be the set of $k \times k$ complex matrices. I am trying to find a sequence of polynomials $P_{n}: M_{k}(\mathbb{C}) \to M_{k}(\mathbb{C})$ (or continuous functions $f_{n}$) such that $P_{n}$ converges to identity matrix $1_{k}$ uniformly for compact subspaces of all matrices with Hilbert–Schimdt norm $\leq 1$, except $0$ matrix, and $P_{n}(0)=0$.
So far I have tried:

1. $P_{n}(A)=1_{k}-(1_{k}-(AA^*)^2)^n$, where $A^*=\overline{A^{T}}$ (but I am running into trouble when A is singular diagonal matrices with H.S. norm $\leq 1$, then the $P_{n}$ does not converge to $1_{K}$)
2. To rectify that I have tried the following:
   $f_{n}(A)=1_{k}-e^{-nAA^*}$, but still the same issue persists (I think).

I will be highly obliged for any suggestion or hint.

Comment: What is an example for $k = 1$?

Comment: for k=1, taking $P_{n}(x)=1-(1-x^2)^n$ works I think.

Comment: @markvs if AA*=0, then is it not true then A=0? as the sum of diagonal elements of AA* is \sum\limits_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|^2=0, then it implies a_{i,j}=0. I could be wrong.

Comment: What is your definition of a polynomial from $M_k(\mathbf{C})$ to itself?

Comment: @YCor I thought, we could define complex Polynomials from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ as linear combination of products of powers of $z$ and $\bar{z}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @YCor If so, then as $M_{k}(\mathbb{C})$ could be thought as $\mathbb{C}^{k^2}$, so every entry of $AA^*$ is a polynomial in $z_{i}$ and $\bar{z_{j}}$.

Comment: @user938363 this is typically *not* a complex polynomial, but indeed is (component-wise) polynomial in the $2k^2$ real variables.